# Create a new dataframe that list the keywords with sum of their respective value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the issue :

I have a dataframe that have a list of keywords.
I have a second dataframe with a list of keywords and values.

The goal is to create a new dataframe that list the keywords with sum of their respective value.

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1':['a','b','b','b','c','d','c','a','z','c'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

keywords = {'col1':['a','b','c']}
letters = keywords['col1']

for x in letters:

    a1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains(x,na=False)] 
    a2 = a1['col2'].sum()
    a3 = {'letter':[x],'sum':[a2]}
    a = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
```

but it only shows

c - 22

Comment: What's your expected output? Where is the second dataframe?

Comment: whould be a dataframe that is :  a - 9 | b - 9 | c - 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1':['a','b','b','b','c','d','c','a','z','c'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

keywords = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c']})
grouped = df.groupby("col1").agg({"col2": "sum"}).reset_index()
keywords.merge(grouped, on="col1", how="left")
```

#### Explanation:

The grouped dataframe sums over the values of `col2` for each unique `col1` value in `df` and so `grouped` is a dataframe with one row for each unique `col1` value that has the sum of `col2` in its `col2` column. Merging them with `how="left"` means you ignore the `col1` entries in `grouped` not in `keywords` and this gets you the desired result.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much kind stranger

Comment: Great! If your problem is solved, please accept the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Of course! You awnsered so fast i couldnt accept the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: and what can i do if d = {'col1':['a 1d1','b xa2','b mx1','b x12','c xas','d 123','c xas','a vx3','z mp','c xg'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]} ? @Jonas

Comment: As in you need to drop the part after the space in col1? Do df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])

Comment: Not like that, since the a|b|c could be at the end or start

Comment: Maybe ask a new question? It's hard to discuss the details in comments